# Android :How can i draw a image a number of time using for loop

Tags: android

I am working in android.

i have these two images:-
[image]

and

[image]

now using for loop i want to draw these image at run time. so please me how can i do this ?

means it will decided at run time that how many time these images should repeat.
finally i want to draw like this:--
[image]

but this ratio may change at run. please help me how can i do this. you may provide me  some example to implement this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: i want to do same thing help me plz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a horizontal LinearLayout.

```
for (int i=0; i < menCount; i++) {

      ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
      imageView.setImageDrawable(arg0);  //provide the drawable as argument.
      hll.addView(imageView);
}
```

do the same for female image too..

Comment: yashwanth sir, what is h11 ? means what should i take here. a image view or something else? like as layout.

Comment: hll is the horizontal linear layout. you declare this layout in the xml, and get a reference to it in the code, after which you start adding the images to it.

Comment: plz give more example on this , i dnt do this by this code, plz more explain about this..

Answer (score 4):

Based on info you gave, it should be roughly like this:

```
// A is the class you want to paint images. It should  be subclass of View class
class A extends View {

    /* Other code... */    

    // You need to overwrite onDraw, this is where drawing to screen is made
    public void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        // x is an array containing the coordinates
        ArrayList<Point> coordinates coors;
        // You need to calculate coordinates in runtime and set them
        x = ...
        for(int i = 0; i < coors.size(); i++) {
          c.drawBitmap(bitmap, coors.get(i).x, coors.get(i).y, null); // Tells system to paint image to coordinates x,y
        }
    }
    /* ... */  
}
```